# Pointwise and uniform convergence sequence of functions UPDATE

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The sequence of functions is given by $\left \{ f_{n}\left ( x \right ) \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, where $f_{n}\left ( x \right )=\frac{nx}{1+n^{p}x^{2}}$, p>1

I have to show that sequence of function $\left \{ f_{n}\left ( x \right ) \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$:

1. Convergence pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$ and find limit function
2. Convergence uniform on $\mathbb{R}$ for $p\geq 2$ otherwise it is not uniform convergence on the whole domain of $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that: $\lim_{n \to \infty } f_{n}= \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{nx}{1+n^{p}x^{2}}=0$. So I found my limit function and now I have to prove that $\frac{nx}{1+n^{p}x^{2}}< \epsilon $. Can I just say that $\frac{1}{n^{p}x^{2}}< \epsilon $, so our $n_{0}=\left [ \frac{1}{n^{p}x^{2}} \right ]+1$?

But how should I do it, when there is p ?

For the second we will use supremum criterium, which means that:

$a_{n}=sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\left | f_{n}\left ( x \right )-f\left ( x \right ) \right |=sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\frac{nx}{1+n^{p}x^{2}}=0$

It is correct? Or do I understand it completely wrong? Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning pointwise convergence, since you know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{nx}{1+n^px^2}=0$ (can you justify it?) you're done. There's nothing else to do.

Concerning uniform convergence, it is not hard to see (using derivatives) that $f_n$ attains its maximum at $\frac1{\sqrt{n^p}}$ and that that maximum is $\frac12n^{1-p/2}$. Now, use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12n^{1-p/2}=0$ if and only if $1-\frac p2<0$, which is equivalent to $p>2$. (Yes, it is $p>2$, not $p\geqslant2$).

Comment: Can I justify it as I update it in my post, or Am I completely wrong? and for the second one, do I use derivation all the time, or just in this case because I am on $R$?

Comment: Yes, you can update your post to justify that $(\forall x\in\mathbb R):\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$. Concerning the second question, using derivatives is the way to go when you are trying to determine the maximum of a differentiable function.

Comment: So can I say$\frac{1}{n^{p}x^{2}}< \epsilon $, so our $n_{0}=\left [ \frac{1}{n^{p}x^{2}} \right ]+1$? Or it is enough to say that denominator is always higher than numerator as n approaches infinity?

Comment: Concerning your first approach, I don't see how you deduce from that that $\frac{nx}{1+n^px^2}<\varepsilon$. And all that you can deduce from the second approach is that the limit, if it exists, is smaller than or equal to $1$.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much